# Is it a good Idea to use a stylesheet to reset css while using asp.net webform?

Tags: asp.net, css

Is it a good Idea to use a stylesheet to reset css while using asp.net webform? I mean contrary to the asp.net MVC, which uses pure HTML and doesn't rely on some magic hidden elements somewhere.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I meant "RESET". I'm worrying about resetting the css like we do in ASP.NET MVC. As I heard that Webform rely on some hidden magic and emits its own HTML.

Comment: It's not hidden magic. Webforms allows you to specify stylesheets and render as you need. [Scott Guthrie's detailed post on ASP.NET 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, Depends on what other magic you're planning to do. :)

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to
>   reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights,
>   margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

-Says Eric Meyer

Related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet).

But anyways, here's a [link](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080419/reset-style-sheets-are-bad/) on why using css reset can be disadvantageous.

Comment: Ok. I'll use the reset sheet then.